# How to Transform a Text in a Value for a Json Variable Using pytho and Scrapy?

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

Im crawling a website that contains informations about cars usign Scrapy

(https://bestcars.uol.com.br/bc/participe/opinioes-proprietarios/teste-do-leitor-jeep/jeep-compass-segunda-geracao/).

But in this website, they put all inside "**<'p'>**" and the string value extracted have a "[ ]" with the name of their variable, and when i put it inside the Item, they appear like this :

```
Item[[Name] Gustavo Spínola Amaral Melo',    
 ' [City] Governador Valadares',   
 ' [State] MG'].
```

When I crawl and get a Json File, the string **Item['UserData']** comes with this output.
There's a way for me to to transformate this "[City]" part inside the string as a variable, or remove it?

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2SR9b.png)
[CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qdQY.jpg)

Comment: Good job but yu should post your code directly here

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the replace function and just removing "[" and "]"? Like this:

```
carName.replace("[", "").replace("]", "")
```